# Como podría hacer para poder ver catálogos issu

Tags: html5, blogger

Quiero saber como podría hacer para que mi blog de **blogger** soporte incrustaciones de **issuu**. Me refiero a que se vea la imagen cuando se esta en portada y esta en moda de resumen. Mi plantilla soporta vídeos de youtube, dailymotion.

No se si me habran podido entender pero dejo la [url del blog](https://bloggerdepueba.blogspot.pe/2017/08/danny-moda-casual-c-12-2017.html) para que vean de lo que estoy hablando, esta url tiene una incrustacion de issuu pero cuando se esta en la home no se puede ver la imagen, en cambio si pongo un video este si se ve en portada. He puesto el video de No eras para mi: Jesse y Joy ft. Yuri y cuando estén en portada se darán cuenta que este se ve muy bien.

Answer (score 0):

Compa, pues issuu te da un código cierto? ese código lo ingresas bajo una etiqueta 
`embed` un ejemplo de como lo uso en wordpress es así:

```
[embed width=550]https://issuu.com/ktm-bike-industries/docs/ktm_imagekatalog2017[/embed]
```

Así pues en Blogger lo que tienes que hacer es similar, insertarlo como embed, te dejo un enlace donde dice como.http://help.issuu.com/hc/en-us/articles/212183338-Embedding-Publications-on-Blogger

Comment: Hola Vulpex, yo estoy inscrito en issuu y cuando subo un pdf, el sitio me proporciona el embed para poder incrustarlo en mi blog y este se vea online, hasta ahi todo bien. Pero el problema esta cuando estoy en la home, el embed de issuu me muestra un color gris como imagen, lo mismo pasa  con el gadget de contenido relacionado ya que no me muestra una imagen, como si lo hace cuando pongo videos..

Comment: Compa, entonces creo que el título no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta, trata de reformular tu pregunta o poner un mejor ejemplo porque en lo personal no entendí. Por otro lado,sea lo sea el error sólo te pasa en el home, entonces puede ser cuestion de .css

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias de todos modos. Voy reformular  mi pregunta.